# Icinga2 Cluster HA - Service stalled in "pending"

Tags: linux, nagios, network-monitoring

I am using Icinga2-2.3.2 cluster HA setup with three nodes in the same zone and database in a seperate server for idodb. All are Cent OS 6.5. Installed IcingaWeb2 in the active master.

Configured four local checks for each node including cluster health check as described in the documentation. Installed Icinga Classi UI in all three nodes, beacuse I am not able to see the local checks configured for nodes in Icinga Web2.

Configs are syncing, checks are executing & all three nodes are connected among them. But the status data are not syncing sometime for Icinga Classic UI.

Whenever the config changes in the master and reload, the config is syncing. After sometime when I checked all three nodes classic ui, some no of hosts & services are stalled in "**pending**" state in one or two nodes with different nos.

But all are ok in config master classic ui and even in the Icinga Web2 everything is ok. Above is one sceanrio, sometimes the local checks are also stalled in pending state.

I have attached the screenshot for reference.
[image]
Please help me to fix  and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue "service status Pending reload" in nagios 3, just adding contact group e.g. Linux support (email group) under Contact groups for service notification resolved my issue.